# Ruby : uninitialized constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby

I have 2 files in a directory:

`user.rb`

```
class User

  def initialize
    @token = SECRETS_DATA.fetch('token')
    @client = Slack::Client.new token: @token
  end

  def get_user(userid)
    userinfo = @client.users_info(user: userid)['user']['profile']['email']
    userinfo.split('@').first
  end
end
```

In a sep file `bot.rb` I have:

require_relative 'user'

User.new.get_user(id)

However this is giving me:

`uninitialized constant Slack::Client (NameError)`

Ive tried using `require user` which gives me - `require': cannot load such file -- user (LoadError)`

Tried `require ./user` which gives me the original error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Slack::Web::Client` here. So the final code in `user.rb` looks like as follows..

```
require 'slack-ruby-client'

class User
 def initialize
  @token = SECRETS_DATA.fetch('token')
  @client = Slack::Web::Client.new token: @token
 end

 def get_user(userid)
  userinfo = @client.users_info(user: userid)['user']['profile']['email']
  userinfo.split('@').first
 end
end
```

Ohhh, Please don't forget to run `gem install slack-ruby-client`

If want we can use `RealTimeClient` in the same way.

Docs: https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client#realtime-client

Answer (score -2):

try adding

```
require 'slack-ruby-client'
```

Comment: I tried adding the slack-api (`require 'slack'`) to the bot.rb file. also tried your suggestion. Still the same error.